# Tables with multirows, coloured cells and horizontal dashed lines.

Tags: tables, multirow, cellcolor

I am making a table with some coloured rows, dashed lines and multi rows. There is a set of issues I am running into, and none of them seem to solve my entire problem (only partially).

Below I would like that the rows with "med" and "var" are separated with a dashed line (what I am doing with `\cdashline{3-12}`). However, when using colors in the cell, the line is covered by the colour. When searching for solution to this, I learned about `hhline`, which helps with the coloured cells, however, does not seem to provide a dashed line.

Also, I am using `makecell` because I need to split the line in the row. This makes a weird colour formatting, as the colour does not fill entire cell. I read somewhere about using `thead` instead, however, my problem remained.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{A}      & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{B}  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{C}       \\ \cline{4-12} 
\multirow{-3}{1cm}{\makecell{Onelong-\\word}} & \multirow{-3}{1cm} { \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} \makecell{ No\\change}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{} & 0.1\%  & 1\%       & 10\%      & 0.1\%  & 1\%     & 10\%      & 0.1\%   & 1\%       & 10\%      \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
&  & med & \makecell{A\\ (B)} & \makecell{C \\  (D)} &  \makecell{ V \\ (D)} &   \makecell{ A \\ (S)} &  T (Y) &  \makecell{Q \\ (A)} &  \makecell{V \\ (V)} &  \makecell{V \\ (V)} &  V (V)  \\  \cdashline{3-12} 

\multicolumn{1}{|p{1cm}|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}none}}  &   \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}A (B)} & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} var & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} \makecell{A \\ (B)} & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} \makecell{A \\ (B)} & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} \makecell{C \\ (D)} & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} \makecell{E\\ (F)} & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} \makecell{B \\ (F)} &  \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} \makecell{C \\ (F)} & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}  \makecell{J \\ (G)} & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} \makecell{L \\ (H)} & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} \makecell{K \\ (B)} \\ \hline   
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Provides me with: 
[image: MWE Table example]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Do you really need all of this? Please read the [documentation of the booktabs package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) for advice on good design of tables.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for this reference. The table I am providing here is just a snippet of my entire table. This seems to be the most concise way to show my results. But reading your reference makes me think whether I want to reconsider some of the formatting.

Comment: The reason I want to grey this particular row and particular column is because I would like to highlight it and refer to it later in the text. In the reference you provided it tells about the best way to present a table. Do you have some similar guide for accenting things in a table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest a simpler layout, no vertical rules, extra row spacing instead of dashed lines, entries at the top of their cells not multirow.  Entries can be highlighted by changing font:

[image: Sample output]

here I have chosen `\itshape`, but `\bfseries` could be used;
or you could use a row color:

[image: Sample with row color]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\definecolor{hrow}{HTML}{EFEFEF}
\newcommand{\hi}{\itshape}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{12}{c}}
  \toprule
  \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}Onelong-\\word \end{tabular}}
  &\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}No\\change \end{tabular}}
  &
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{A}
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{B}
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{C}\\
  \cmidrule(lr){4-6}
  \cmidrule(lr){7-9}
  \cmidrule(lr){10-12}
  &&
  &0.1\%&1\%&10\%
  &0.1\%&1\%&10\%
        &0.1\%&1\%&10\%\\
  \midrule
  none&A(B)&med&A&C&V&A&T(Y)&Q&V&V&V(V)\\
  &&&(B)&(D)&(D)&(S)&&(A)&(V)&(V)&\\[.5ex]
  &&var&A&A&C&E&B&C&J&L&K\\
  &&&(B)&(B)&(D)&(F)&(F)&(F)&(G)&(H)&(B)\\
  \midrule
  \hi one&\hi A(B)&\hi med&\hi A&\hi C&\hi V&\hi A&\hi T(Y)&\hi Q&\hi V&\hi V&\hi V(V)\\
  \hi &&&\hi (B)&\hi (D)&\hi (D)&\hi (S)&&\hi (A)&\hi (V)&\hi (V)&\\[.5ex]
  \hi &&\hi var&\hi A&\hi A&\hi C&\hi E&\hi B&\hi C&\hi J&\hi L&\hi K\\
  \hi &&&\hi (B)&\hi (B)&\hi (D)&\hi (F)&\hi (F)&\hi (F)&\hi (G)&\hi (H)&\hi (B)\\
  \midrule
  two&A(B)&med&A&C&V&A&T(Y)&Q&V&V&V(V)\\
  &&&(B)&(D)&(D)&(S)&&(A)&(V)&(V)&\\[.5ex]
  &&var&A&A&C&E&B&C&J&L&K\\
  &&&(B)&(B)&(D)&(F)&(F)&(F)&(G)&(H)&(B)\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\clearpage

\begin{tabular}{*{12}{c}}
  \toprule
  \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}Onelong-\\word \end{tabular}}
  &\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}No\\change \end{tabular}}
  &
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{A}
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{B}
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{C}\\
  \cmidrule(lr){4-6}
  \cmidrule(lr){7-9}
  \cmidrule(lr){10-12}
  &&
  &0.1\%&1\%&10\%
  &0.1\%&1\%&10\%
  &0.1\%&1\%&10\%\\
  \midrule
  none&A(B)&med&A&C&V&A&T(Y)&Q&V&V&V(V)\\
  &&&(B)&(D)&(D)&(S)&&(A)&(V)&(V)&\\[.5ex]
  &&var&A&A&C&E&B&C&J&L&K\\
  &&&(B)&(B)&(D)&(F)&(F)&(F)&(G)&(H)&(B)\\
  \midrule
  \rowcolor{hrow} one&A(B)&med&A&C&V&A&T(Y)&Q&V&V&V(V)\\
  \rowcolor{hrow} &&&(B)&(D)&(D)&(S)&&(A)&(V)&(V)&\\[.5ex]
  \rowcolor{hrow} &&var&A&A&C&E&B&C&J&L&K\\
  \rowcolor{hrow} &&&(B)&(B)&(D)&(F)&(F)&(F)&(G)&(H)&(B)\\
  \midrule
  two&A(B)&med&A&C&V&A&T(Y)&Q&V&V&V(V)\\
  &&&(B)&(D)&(D)&(S)&&(A)&(V)&(V)&\\[.5ex]
  &&var&A&A&C&E&B&C&J&L&K\\
  &&&(B)&(B)&(D)&(F)&(F)&(F)&(G)&(H)&(B)\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, this looks very pleasing! Thank you for the tip on the highlighting. I think the cell colour looks nicer than emphsise/italics. I mentioned also that I was interested in highlighting both the column and the row. However, I think maybe I could skip the column and somehow emphasise the information I need in the text, and only focus on the row. Also, I like the midrules for the A, B, C elements. I learned a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccccccccccc}[vlines,cell-space-limits=3pt,color-inside]
\Hline
  \Block{2-1}{Onelong-\\word} & \Block{2-1}{No\\change} & \Block{2-1}{} & \Block{1-3}{A} &&& \Block{1-3}{B} &&& \Block{1-3}{C} \\ 
\Hline
  & & & 0.1\% & 1\% & 10\% & 0.1\% & 1\% & 10\% & 0.1\% & 1\% & 10\% \\ 
\Hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
  \Block{2-1}{none} & \Block{2-1}{A (B)} & med & \Block{}{A\\ (B)} & \Block{}{C \\ (D)} & \Block{}{ V \\ (D)} & \Block{}{ A \\ (S)} 
  & T (Y) &  \Block{}{Q \\ (A)} & \Block{}{V \\ (V)} & \Block{}{V \\ (V)} &  V (V)  \\  
\Hline[tikz=dashed]
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
  &  &  var &  \Block{}{A \\ (B)} & \Block{}{A \\ (B)} & \Block{}{C \\ (D)} & \Block{}{E\\ (F)} &  
  \Block{}{B \\ (F)} &   \Block{}{C \\ (F)} & \Block{}{J \\ (G)} &  \Block{}{L \\ (H)} & \Block{}{K \\ (B)} \\ 
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

However, I recommend a design more in the spirit of `booktabs`, as suggested by Andrew Swann.